# It is possible to use DrawText or TextOut text rendering in GDI

Tags: c++, gdi, drawtext, textout

I am trying to render some text on screen. I am using GDI, C++ and trying to use DrawText and TextOut functions to render my text. My text only appears when program starts, and then text immediatily disappear. Am i able to use it with GDI and if i am, then how?

```
HDC         hDC;
PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
HFONT       font;
LOGFONT LogFont;
```

...

```
hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
```

GDI render code

```
    LogFont.lfStrikeOut = 0;
    LogFont.lfUnderline = 0;
    LogFont.lfHeight = 42;
    LogFont.lfEscapement = 0;
    LogFont.lfItalic = TRUE;

    font = CreateFontIndirect(&LogFont);
    SelectObject(hDC, font);
    TextOut(hDC, 20, 18, "Some text", 14);

    DeleteObject(font);

EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
```

Using code from [this lesson](http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson15.htm).

Comment: `My text only appears when program starts, and then text immediatily disappear` This usually happens when drawing is done not in WM_PAINT message handler.

Comment: I am calling function onPaint() in VM_PAINT message handler and doing all drawing in onPaint() function. This could be problem?

Comment: Thanks you so much Alex Farber! I wish i could accept your answer, but you just commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`My text only appears when program starts, and then text immediately disappear` This usually happens when drawing is done not in WM_PAINT message handler.